# Android Studio Broadcast Programming

Tags: android-studio, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am learning to develop apps for Android but I am stuck with this topic:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

I have visited numerous sites with examples, downloaded source code and tried in two different computers with Android Studio and tried in a virtual and physical device, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

MANIFEST

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            <action android:name="com.example.myapplication.TEST_BROADCAST" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

MyReceiver.java

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
String logPrefix = "Android : ";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(logPrefix, "Broadcast received");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String logPrefix = "Android : ";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(logPrefix, "The onCreate() event");
}


public void broadcastIntent(View view){
    Log.d(logPrefix, "Sending broadcast...");
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myapplication.TEST_BROADCAST");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: I see no code that ever calls broadcastIntent.  What logs are missing from logcat?

Comment: broadcastIntent is called from a button pressed from the interface. Logcat displays "Sending broadcast...", therefore I know the function is executed but I have no way of knowing if the broadcast actually was sent. "Broadcast received" is never logged after executing broadcastIntent, neither toggling airplane mode nor with TIME_TICK